# pytest plugin for asserting file contents are identical

Tags: pytest

I find myself copy/pasting this function into all my projects and using it for comparing files in pytest:

```
import filecmp
from pathlib import Path

def assert_files_equal(p1: Path, p2: Path):
    if not filecmp.cmp(p1, p2):
        raise AssertionError(f"contents of {p1} and {p2} are different")
```

It works, but the problem is, it doesn't tell me what the difference is when there is a failure.  Is there some pytest plugin that would alert me to the difference?  If so, I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Don’t assert file contents are equal, assert their `diff` is empty. You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html to help.